# Pandoc TOC links point to wrong page

Tags: latex, pandoc, pdflatex

When I generate a PDF document from latex using Pandoc, the TOC links are incorrect. Links to parts and chapters always link to one page before where it should link. I think this is a result of the template forcing a page break before each chapter and part so that each of these begins on a new page. I want chapters and parts to begin on new pages but I would also like links to take users to the actual page the content starts on. I am using the default Pandoc template and the following options:

- --toc
- --top-level-division=part
- --variable documentclass:'report'

Comment: please post some reproducible code. It works fine on my machine with just those options, so it might be something else from your document.

Comment: Please state the version of Pandoc you are using: `pandoc --version` ...